# how to prevent Innob db spiking at 97% Disk I/O Utilization

Tags: mysql, high-availability, innodb

Our database(InnobDb) is spiking at 99% I/O at random times. After the spike it goes down to about 2% until it spikes agian. There are not some "super" queries that are running in these intervals. We are running a vp on digitalocean with 16 GB Ram, 8 CoreProcessor and 160GB SSD Disk. Out databse contains 1BG of data. We suspect there is something wrong with our config- We have 13 GB memory we are not using. Does anybody know whats wring? Do i need to provide more info?

Link to screenshot of spikes: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJ6kx.jpg

link to my.conf: 
http://paste.bradleygill.com/index.php?paste_id=1346993

link to mysql show status: 
http://paste.bradleygill.com/index.php?paste_id=1346995

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had 2 problems:

1) We had one mysql query that used three joins. Turns out this function was crashing Mysql. We rewrote this query to use 4 mysql queries without joins and that solved that problem. (Bit of a hot-fix, we will probably rewrite the function so it is possible to cache it).

2) We were experiencing around 99.9 % I/O wait when we only used 10% cache https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121324/mysql-only-using-10-of-cache . We tried to edit the mysql config (quoted at the bottom). This helped a lot but did not fix the problem. It turned out another user on the shared server was causing 99.8% I/O spikes. After contacting our server provider they moving the server to another partition and the problem was fixed.

```
table_open_cache = 1024 
sort_buffer_size = 4M 
read_buffer_size = 128k 
query_cache_size= 128M 
query_cache_type = 1 
tmp_table_size = 64M 
thread_cache_size = 20 
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 512M 
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M 
innodb_log_file_size = 64M 
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M 
innodb_file_per_table innodb_file_format = Barracuda
```